# How can I improve this? using typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

```
const ProgressBarVertical: React.FC<ProgressProps> = ({
  Levelorder,
  currentLevel,
 }) => {
  if (Levelorder === 0) {
       switch (currentLevel) {
         case 0:
           return <View style={styles.progressIncompleteFirst} />
         default:
           return <View style={styles.progressCompleteFirst} />
       }
  } else if (Levelorder > currentLevel) {
     return <View style={styles.progressIncomplete} />
  } else if (Levelorder < currentLevel) {
     return <View style={styles.progressComplete} />
  } else {
     return <View style={styles.progressIncomplete} />
  }
```

I'm was in a rush and I did my conditions like this, But I feel I still can improve this. Can someone show me how?

Comment: Repost to CodeReview.SE

Comment: You don't need so many `else if's` - simply `if() return;` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any refactoring look for things that repeat and try to make them not repeat. The first thing I notice is that you render a `<View />` many times, just with a different `style` prop. So what if you rendered that once instead?

```
const ProgressBarVertical: React.FC<ProgressProps> = ({
  Levelorder,
  currentLevel,
}) => {
    return <View style={getStyle(Levelorder, currentLevel)} />
}
```

Now you can implement `getStyle`. Note that by using an early return you can keep the number of conditional curly braces down quite a bit.

```
function getStyle(Levelorder: number, currentLevel: number): ViewStyle {
    if (Levelorder === 0) {
        return currentLevel === 0 ?
            styles.progressIncompleteFirst :
            styles.progressCompleteFirst
    }

    if (Levelorder < currentLevel) return styles.progressComplete
    
    return styles.progressIncomplete
}
```

The first if handles the special case where `Levelorder` is zero. The second `if` handles the completed case, and then last just return the *only* other option (equal to or grater than) if neither of the previous two returns were executed.